# specify jquery tooltip position by css class value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu that position can change by included div class. I am using jquery [tooltip widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position)

```
.menu-top{...}
.menu-top .button{...}

.menu-left{...}
.menu-left .button{..}

.menu-right{...}
.menu-right .button{..}
```

Html is like this

```
<div class="menu-top">
  <div class="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="menu item 1">
  <div class="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="menu item 2">
  <div class="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="menu item 3">
  .....
  ... 
</div>
```

When I change div class as **menu-left**, it appears left of the page. But tooltip appears top of the menu item. How can I change data-placement with jquery by menu class name? I am new at jquery.

Comment: data-placement="bottom" if you want it at bottom

Comment: would depend on plugin you use for tooltip, we don't know what you are using

Comment: I can set manually data-placement, how can I change with jquery by menu class name

Comment: A JSFiddle would be helpful to see and debug your problem. As charlietfl said, we don't know what you are using.

Answer (score -1):

You can change position of your tool-tip by changing `data-placement` value
Eg:

```
<div class="menu-top">
  <div class="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="menu item 1">   //TOP Position
  <div class="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="menu item 1"> //Bottom Position
  <div class="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="menu item 1"> //LEFT Position
  <div class="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="menu item 1">//RIGHT Position
</div>
```

`Value` of data-placement depends upon the **PLUGIN** you use.